# Matplotlib why does colorbar y label disappear with multiple colorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, colorbar

Why does my colorbar label "y1" disappear when I add the second colorbar?

If I remove the colorbar for ax2, then the label shows on the first colorbar.

Using Python 3.8

**Stand-Alone Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
%matplotlib inline 
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    
x = [-15000, -2000, 0, 5000, 6000, 11000, 18000, 21000, 25000, 36000, 62000]
beta = [1000, 200, -800, 100, 1000, -2000, -5000, -5000, -15000, -21000, -1500]
y = [0.01, 0.2, 1.3, 0.35, 0.88, 2.2, 2.5, 1.25, 3.4, 4.1, 2.1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7.5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex = ax1)
fig.execute_constrained_layout()
fig.suptitle('Suptitle')


vals = ax1.scatter(x, beta, c=y, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap='rainbow')
ax1.set_title('ax1', style='italic');
cbax1=ax1.inset_axes([1.1, 0, 0.03, 1], transform=ax1.transAxes)
cbar1=fig.colorbar(vals, cax=cbax1, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical')
cbar1.ax.set_ylabel('y1')
cbar1.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')

ax2.scatter(x, y, c=y, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap='rainbow')
ax2.set_title('ax2', style='italic');
vals2 = vals
cbax2 = ax2.inset_axes([1.1, 0, 0.03, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes)
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(vals2, cax=cbax2, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical')
cbar2.ax.set_ylabel('y2')
cbar2.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bug. You can set the labels after plotting:

```
# Your other codes

# also can use `cbax1` instead of `cbar1.ax`
cbar2.ax.set_ylabel('y2')
cbar2.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')

cbar1.ax.set_ylabel('y1')
cbar1.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: weird, guess that's what bugs are, but works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Made two correction in your code. I am also using Python 3.8

```
# ---> Assign the second scatter plot to vals2
vals2 = ax2.scatter(x, y, c=y, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap='rainbow')
ax2.set_title('ax2', style='italic');
# ---> comment below line.
#vals2 = vals
```

result:

[image: Resulting plots]

In adition, you can add label to colorbar() function like this:

```
cbar1=fig.colorbar(vals, cax=cbax1, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical', label='y1')
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(vals2, cax=cbax2, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical', label='y2')
```

Try restarting the kernel if you still face this issue.

Comment: thanks, that is really helpful. when I do `cbar2 = fig.colorbar(vals, cax=cbax, format = '%1.2g', orientation='vertical', label='y2')` and then `cbar2.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')` it doesn't move the label to the left side; do you know how to fix that?

Comment: just realised the issue in your code. even your earlier code will work with two changes.

you have not assigned your second scatter plot to variable vals2, instead you copies it from vals. That was the issue. do this...

vals2 = ax2.scatter(x, y, c=y, norm=mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap='rainbow')

and comment below line:
#vals2 = vals

even your code will work now.

Comment: actually it doesn't work, that's why I tried to copy vals2

Comment: its working for me. I have updated my answer with result.

Comment: the y1 label is on the right, not left. the only way to get it to work is to do it is like the first answer, it is a bug and needs to be at the end